# How do I code a program that will create drop down lists from input and populate columns in another sheet with drop downs

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and currently know how to create Macros using the "Record Macro" option. I need to code something that does multiple steps in VBA.

I will have an unknown number of columns that I need the program to go through and check if the second row has a value in it.(These columns and rows will be input from a user so the number of columns or entries per row is unknown).

The values under each column are the possible categories a user will later choose from for that specific variable. So in Sheet 1 there is a variable "Sex" there will be one row under it saying "female" and another row under that saying "male". These have to be made into a drop down list and pasted under another sheet (Sheet2) in which the same column names (Sex) will now have drop downs under them.

Steps to take:

1) IF Column(i)'s Row 2 is not empty

2) Then define all rows below it as a list and make a drop down of this list

3) Then paste this drop down under a column that matches the name of the Column(i) in another sheet

## SHEET 1 (what i have)

```
Age      | Sex    | Race   | Height 
------------------------------------
[EMPTY]  |Female  |Asian   |[EMPTY]     
[EMPTY]  |Male    |Black   |[EMPTY]          
[EMPTY]  |[EMPTY] |Hispanic|[EMPTY]          
[EMPTY]  |[EMPTY] |Native A|[EMPTY]          
[EMPTY]  |[EMPTY] |White   |[EMPTY] 
[EMPTY]  |[EMPTY] |Other   |[EMPTY]
```

---

## SHEET 2 (what I want)

```
AGE      | Sex               | Race                | Height
------------------------------------------------------------
[EMPTY]  | [dropdown of sex] | [dropdown of race]  |[EMPTY]
```

Comment: Hi welcome Stack overflow... have you tried coding if yes post that..

Comment: This won't be easy to explain... but I'll try...

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a somewhat "general" piece of code (commented):

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddDropDowns()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iDropDown As Long

    With Worksheets("DropDownData") '<--| reference "Data" sheet
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through its 2nd(!) row non empty cells
            '          |         DropDown      | dropdown |      dropdown        |                      dropdown                                                             |
            '          |         sheet         | counter  |      header          |                validation formula                                                         |
            AddDropDown Worksheets("DropDowns"), iDropDown, cell.Offset(-1).value, "='" & .Name & "'!" & cell.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(cell.EntireColumn) - 1).Address '<--| add current cell column dropdown in "DropDowns" sheet
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub

Sub AddDropDown(sht As Worksheet, dropDownCounter As Long, header As String, validationFormula As String)
    With sht.Range("A1").Offset(, dropDownCounter) '<--| reference passed sheet row 1 passed column
        .Cells(1, 1) = header '<--| write header
        With .Cells(2, 1).Validation '<--| reference 'Validation' property of cell 1 row below currently referenced one
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=validationFormula
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End With
    dropDownCounter = dropDownCounter + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: @KatyTorres, did you get through it?

Comment: user3598756 YES! This was a great help and mostly what I needed to do, Thank you very much! I now have to make sure I do a routine that also copies the non-categorical variables onto the "DropdOWNS" sheet

Comment: You are welcome. Then please mark answer as accepted. Thank you

Comment: I used this same exact code and I am having another macro call both the `AddDropDownsEnroll
    and AddDropDownEnroll` macros. But when I do, It gives me an error that says "Argument Not Optional". Would you happen to know how to fix this? It seems as if the arguments needed to run `AddDropDownEnroll` are not being passed somehow.

Comment: There it would need your new code to be analyzed: post a new question!

Answer (score 2):

First, you have sheet `A` and sheet `B`.

## Sheet B:

```
+----+-----------+---+---------------+----+---+-------------+--------+---+-------------+----------+---+--------------+----+
|    |     A     | B |       C       | D  | E |      F      |   G    | H |      I      |    J     | K |      L       | M  |
+----+-----------+---+---------------+----+---+-------------+--------+---+-------------+----------+---+--------------+----+
|  1 |           |   | myAge         |  5 |   | mySex       | Female |   | myRace      | Asian    |   | myHeight     | 25 |
|  2 | SheetName |   | B!$D$1:$D$101 |  6 |   | B!$G$1:$G$2 | Male   |   | B!$J$1:$J$6 | Black    |   | B!$M$1:$M$66 | 30 |
|  3 | B         |   |               |  7 |   |             |        |   |             | hispanic |   |              | 35 |
|  4 |           |   |               |  8 |   |             |        |   |             | Native A |   |              | 40 |
|  5 |           |   |               |  9 |   |             |        |   |             | White    |   |              | 45 |
|  6 |           |   |               | 10 |   |             |        |   |             | Other    |   |              | 50 |
|  7 |           |   |               | 11 |   |             |        |   |             |          |   |              | 55 |
|  8 |           |   |               | 12 |   |             |        |   |             |          |   |              | 60 |
|  9 |           |   |               | 13 |   |             |        |   |             |          |   |              | 65 |
| 10 |           |   |               | 14 |   |             |        |   |             |          |   |              | 70 |
| 11 |           |   |               | 15 |   |             |        |   |             |          |   |              | 75 |
| 12 |           |   |               | 16 |   |             |        |   |             |          |   |              | 80 |
| 13 |           |   |               | 17 |   |             |        |   |             |          |   |              | 85 |
| 14 |           |   |               | 18 |   |             |        |   |             |          |   |              | 90 |
+----+-----------+---+---------------+----+---+-------------+--------+---+-------------+----------+---+--------------+----+
```

Put the formulas in every cell as you see en the next text:

```
+----+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| C2 | B!$D$1:$D$101 | =ADDRESS(ROW(D1),COLUMN(D1),,,SheetName)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(D1)+COUNTA(D:D)-1,COLUMN(D1),,,) |
| F2 | B!$G$1:$G$2   | =ADDRESS(ROW(G1),COLUMN(G1),,,SheetName)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(G1)+COUNTA(G:G)-1,COLUMN(G1),,,) |
| I2 | B!$J$1:$J$6   | =ADDRESS(ROW(J1),COLUMN(J1),,,SheetName)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(J1)+COUNTA(J:J)-1,COLUMN(J1),,,) |
| L2 | B!$M$1:$M$66  | =ADDRESS(ROW(M1),COLUMN(M1),,,SheetName)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(M1)+COUNTA(M:M)-1,COLUMN(M1),,,) |
+----+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now you set every name this way:

[image]

Press `New...`

[image]

Set the range names using this:

```
+---+----+-----------+-------------------+
|   | A  |     B     |         C         |
+---+----+-----------+-------------------+
| 1 | A2 | SheetName | =B!$A$3           |
| 2 | C1 | myAge     | =INDIRECT(B!$C$2) |
| 3 | F1 | mySex     | =INDIRECT(B!$F$2) |
| 4 | I1 | myRace    | =INDIRECT(B!$I$2) |
| 5 | L1 | myHeight  | =INDIRECT(B!$L$2) |
+---+----+-----------+-------------------+
```

## Sheet A:

```
+---+-----+-----+------+--------+
|   |  A  |  B  |  C   |   D    |
+---+-----+-----+------+--------+
| 1 | Age | Sex | Race | Height |
| 2 |     |     |      |        |
| 3 |     |     |      |        |
| 4 |     |     |      |        |
| 5 |     |     |      |        |
| 6 |     |     |      |        |
+---+-----+-----+------+--------+
```

## In a regular module:

```
Sub addComboBox()
    Dim rngHeaders As Range
    Dim i As Range
    Dim r
    Dim c
    Dim Nm As String
    Dim n As Name

    '1
    'take all the cells in the first row
    'just the headers

    r = 1 'is just the fist row!
    c = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

    Set rngHeaders = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, c))

    For Each i In rngHeaders
        Nm = "my" & i.Value
        For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
            If Nm = n.Name Then
                With i.Offset(1, 0).Resize(20, 1).Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & Nm
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = ""
                    .ErrorTitle = ""
                    .InputMessage = ""
                    .ErrorMessage = ""
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
            End If
        Next n
    Next i
End Sub
```

## Note:

For each header you have in sheet `A` you will need to set it in sheet `B` with the same name plus "`my`", this way: `myAge`, `mySex`, and so on.

This tutorial, will guide you to set a list with dropdown menus in that headers, if you want to set the dropdown menu to more cells (not just the 2nd cell of every header) you need to replace this line With `i.Offset(1, 0).Validation` whith this `With i.Offset(1, 0).Resize(20, 1).Validation` where that `20` is the number of rows you want to set, and the result will be this:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
|    |          A          |          B          |          C           |           D            |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
|  1 | Age                 | Sex                 | Race                 | Height                 |
|  2 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
|  3 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
|  4 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
|  5 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
|  6 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
|  7 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
|  8 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
|  9 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 10 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 11 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 12 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 13 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 14 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 15 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 16 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 17 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 18 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 19 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 20 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
| 21 | [dropdown of myAge] | [dropdown of mySex] | [dropdown of myRace] | [dropdown of myHeight] |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: ++ for the details and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of a tutorial to get you started.  I left out some of the detals for you to work through... not sure how good you are with coding, but this is the basic idea.

Step 1.  Try to do it manually.  You'll need to use the "Data" menu, "Data Validation" button.  Validation type is List.  For validation source, click the button to the right of the source textbox and then select the cells from sheet1.

Step 2. Do it manually again, but this time use Record Macro to generate the code.  It should look something like this:

```
Selection.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$3"
```

Step 3. Take your macro code and put it into a sub.

```
Sub SetUpOneValidator
    Selection.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$3"
End Sub
```

Step 4. Add arguments to the sub so that it will work for any of the columns

```
Sub SetUpOneValidator(byval column as integer, byval count as integer)
    Dim s as string
    s = ComputeFormulaForRange(column, count) 'You'll have to write this yourself
    Sheets("Sheet2").cells(2, column).Validdation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=s
End Sub
```

Step 5. Write an "outer" sub to call your sub for each column

```
Sub DoMyWork
    Dim x as integer, n as integer
    while x <= Sheets("sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
        n = DetectRowCountForColumn(x) 'You'll have to write this yourself!
        SetUpOneValidator x, n
        x = x + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: John, Thank you for your Tutorial. It was a good idea to do it manually and then record it. The only issue with this is that the project I am working on will be sent to a user who wont be doing anything manually other than extracting the finished sheet with the headers and drop downs.